# Why are regular expressions taking the helm in my JavaScript, and how do I insist "this is a string"?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, google-chrome, firefox

I have JavaScript code like:

```
 quotes = [];
 quotes[quotes.length] = "ABC quote";
 quotes[quotes.length] = "DEF quote";
 ...
```

One of the lines in particular is:

```
quotes[quotes.length] = "Mark Twain said, &apos;The secret source of humor itself is not joy but sorrow.  There is no humor in Heaven.&apos;<br /><a href=\"/pain\/">Humor Delivers Pain</a>";
```

Chrome is complaining about that line, over a hundred lines in, which I tried to address to having apostrophes replaced by &apos;. However, it is still complaining about this line, and the syntax highlighting is apparently not seeing the opening double quotation mark, but only the regular expression, **/pain/">Humor Delivers Pain</**.

Everything before that expression is highlighted as intended, as strings, even though such regular expression strings are a boilerplate substring; the previous line, like those before it reads:

```
quotes[quotes.length] = "The author was shaped by M.K. Gandhi. Here is why he is taking leave of Gandhi.<br /><a href=\"/gandhi/\">Farewell to Gandhi</a>";
```

And even though this contains what could be a regular expression literal inside the quote mark, it is interpreted as intended, as a double quoted string containing escaped quotes.

The page where I am trying this out is http://JonathansCorner.com/firestorm/ . It is meant to print out a notice at the top of the page, and changing links. Right now it is crashing on the line intended as a Mark Twain quote.

Firefox raises a complaint about the Twain quote, saying that there is a missing semicolon before the statement. I'm not sure where that's coming from; could this be secondary damage from a quotation higher up?

The JavaScript itself is at http://jonathanscorner.com/include/deprecation_notice.js.

--EDIT--

@Lightness, the problem manifests for a two-line sample of the immediately preceding line and then the line where the error is drawn. There is the same error, with an earlier script line indicated, at:

```
quotes = [];
quotes[quotes.length] = "The author was shaped by M.K. Gandhi. Here is why he is taking leave of Gandhi.<br /><a href=\"/gandhi/\">Farewell to Gandhi</a>";
quotes[quotes.length] = "Mark Twain said, &apos;The secret source of humor itself is not joy but sorrow.  There is no humor in Heaven.&apos;<br /><a href=\"/pain\/">Humor Delivers Pain</a>";
```

Comment: The syntax coloring should be a strong hint...

Comment: Almost certainly secondary damage, yes. You should create an isolated 10-line testcase that exhibits the issue.

Comment: "My code isn't properly highlighted, and browsers can't parse my code! It's certainly the fault of the highlighter and parsers!"

Comment: @Tinctorius, may I ask why you consider this insult essential? I, like many other programmers, post diagnostics to ask about why my code is causing trouble, not a complaint that Firefox and Chrome don't legitimately handle JavaScript.

Comment: What insult? I only see a parody of the conclusions you draw from your findings.

Comment: @Tinctorius, I acknowledge that browsers may be assumed to have secondary damage in some places, but I would scarcely infer that Chrome and Firefox would have the same secondary damage; ergo my reference to secondary damage was to fault in my code rather than the browser. I invite others to my open source software collection at http://JonathansCorner.com/etc/etc2.html and see how many of the projects are consistent with a degree of developer who blames problems on the environment.

Answer (score 5):

```
<a href=\"/pain\/">
```

The second double quote isn't escaped. `\"` not `/"`.

It would probably be more reliable to store these quotes in a plain text file or database, and escape them automatically. Escaping a lot of text by hand is a chore.